# Shared Pointer ambiguous call / undefined reference to call

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ambiguous

My program compiles and runs fine with MSVC but if I compile it with linux with an intel compiler it suddenly has linking problems:
`undefined reference to Model::Model(boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::shared_ptr<DEM::World>)`

In think/guess my problem might have to do with an ambiguous function call. For some reason the shared_pointer argument in the constructor has an ambiguous call to memory as shown in the picture below, when I try to navigate to the source.:

[image: Ambigous call]

The World object is just a normal object.

I don't understand why this call is ambiguous and how to solve it.

Comment: Your first argument is `const` in the definition, but you might be declaring it non const (from your linker error). These constructors have different signatures after mangling, hence the link error.

Comment: "undefined reference" is not the same as ambigous function call (if you're talking about overloaded functions). It means that the compilation unit (i.e. the .cpp file) containing that function hasn't been included in the link, or some macro or `using namespace` has changed the meaning of the function in the place where it's defined compared to the place it's used (yes this is like an overloaded function but like you've created an overload by accident).

Comment: To complement @ArthurTacca explanation, an ambiguous function call would be a compiler error, and not a linker error. The compiler knows what function needs to be called, but the linker does not find such a function.

Comment: @JorgeBellon If const is at the very top level (i.e. this comment applies to `char * const` vs `char*` but not `const char*` vs `char*`), then it counts as the same function signature.

Comment: @DJKlomp It would help a lot to see the full compilation and linker output.

Comment: You're right. Another posibility is mixing compilers/STL by accident. Pre C++11, string was declared in `std` namespace and then in `std::__cxx11` namespace. Intel compiler does not ship its own standard library, but instead uses GCC's.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, thanks it was indeed a namespace issue and I was looking in the complete wrong direction. I still don't understand why visual studio (or resharper) complains about an ambiguous function call, but apparently they can resolve it during compilation.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, if you write it in an answer or just copy your comment in an answer I can give you credit and mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"undefined reference" is not the same as ambigous function call (if you're talking about overloaded functions). It means that the compilation unit (i.e. the .cpp file) containing that function hasn't been included in the link, or some macro or using namespace has changed the meaning of the function in the place where it's defined compared to the place it's used (yes this is like an overloaded function but like you've created an overload by accident).